# For loop pushing to array twice despite modulo if statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object that is populated with college data from a CSV. I am trying to pull data from the object into another array to display with google charts.

Problem is that in the first modulo check it is pushing the data into the array twice. I don't know why either as in console checks it only runs once like it should.

See if i % 10 == 0

```
selectedStateArray = states[Object.keys(states)[selectedState]];
console.log(selectedStateArray);
collegeData = [];

for (var i = 0; i < selectedStateArray.length; i++) {

    if (i % 10 === 0) {
        collegeData.push(selectedStateArray[i]);
        console.log('i modulo 10: ' + selectedStateArray[i]);
    }

    if (year2010.classList.contains('active') && i % 8 === 0 || i % 9 === 0) {
        collegeData.push(selectedStateArray[i]);
    } else if (year2011.classList.contains('active') && i % 6 === 0 || i % 7 === 0) {
        collegeData.push(selectedStateArray[i]);
    } else if (year2012.classList.contains('active') && i % 4 === 0 || i % 5 === 0) {
        collegeData.push(selectedStateArray[i]);
        // console.log('i modulo 4 and 5: '+i);
    }

};
```

Comment: Please add braces to your if statement, like `if (a && (b || c))`. This clearifies what you want to do (and sometimes fixes a bug).

Comment: ...and the length of selectedStatearray is...?

Comment: The if/elseif chain may be at fault, depending on what you want to do, because of the operator precedence differences between `&&` and `||`.  (the `&&` binds more tightly). As Jeremy mentioned, you probably need `()` groups around the `||` conditions if they are to be compared together.

Comment: Thanks Mike and Jeremy I will keep that in mind when coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add a short circuit for the loop [`continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue):

> The **continue statement** terminates execution of the statements in the current iteration of the current or labeled loop, and continues execution of the loop with the next iteration.

```
if (i % 10 === 0) {
    collegeData.push(selectedStateArray[i]);
    console.log('i modulo 10: ' + selectedStateArray[i]);
    continue; // <----------------------------------------- add this to prevent more push!
}
```

Comment: @Pier-LucGendreau, not really. it's a normal language feature for this case.

Comment: Thank you Nina - I didn't know about continue before this. I will definitely be using this in the future. Solved my problem.